# Grafana + Graphite + Templating: default value

Tags: grafana

Given I've got such configuration for templating [image]

After adding it the value "dev" is selected by default. How can I do, that prod would be selected by default?

Comment: Have you tried changing the query to `mysystem.{prod,dev}`?